# Helium balloons

Tags: air-travel

Is it possible to take a helium balloon on an aircraft, I am thinking of taking a balloon on for a birthday gift.  I would be grateful if anyone knows, rather than ask an airline.

Comment: What is the problem with asking the airline? They'd know.

Answer (score 4):

I would not recommend it, and would be surprised if an airline allows it. An aircraft cabin is kept at reduced pressure, and there is a danger of the balloon bursting.

While that might in itself not be very dangerous (and helium is an inert gas) the explosion might cause fear and alarm in the passengers.

Some of the helium balloons you can buy are not even made of rubber (which might expand a little without bursting) but of rigid thin printed plastic.

If the balloon is not inflated but is supplied with a separate helium canister, the same applies.

You really **must** ask the airline (or simply let it be confiscated).

Comment: I thought all helium balloons were made of foil because it diffuses through rubber too fast.